# помогите избавиться от вложенного перебора

Tags: python, алгоритм

Вот есть такая задачка и наивное [решение](https://gist.github.com/chuckis/0e29575719b9c7ca619d458144ceb6f8):

Решение не подходит по временной сложности, помоему.
***Вопрос***: *как правильно решаются такие задачи, подскажите пожалуйста*

***Задача***:

```
# 1.Cannonballs
# 
# A new kind of cannon is being tested. The cannon shoots cannonballs in a fixed direction. Each cannonball flies horizontally until it hits the ground, and then it rests there. Cannonballs are shot from different heights, so they hit the ground at different points.
# You are given two zero-indexed arrays, A and B, containing M and N integers respectively. Array A describes the landscape in the direction along which the cannon is shooting. Elements of array A represent the height of the ground, going from the cannon outwards. Array B contains levels from which consecutive cannonballs are shot.
# Assume that a cannonball is shot at level H.
# Let I be the smallest index, such that 0 < I < M and A[I] ≥ H. The cannonball falls at position I − 1 and increases the ground level A[I−1] by 1.
# If there is no such I, and H > A[I] for all 0 ≤ I < M, then the cannonball flies beyond the horizon and has no effect on the result.
# If H ≤ A[0], then the cannonball ricochets away and has no effect on the result either.
# Write a function:
# def solution(A, B)
# that, given arrays A and B, simulates the flight of the cannonballs and returns the final contents of array A (denoted by A1) representing the final shape of the ground along the line of fire.
# For example, given the following arrays A and B, of size M = 9 and N = 11 respectively:
#   A[0] = 1    A[1] = 2    A[2] = 0
#   A[3] = 4    A[4] = 3    A[5] = 2
#   A[6] = 1    A[7] = 5    A[8] = 7

#   B[0] = 2    B[1] = 8    B[2] = 0
#   B[3] = 7    B[4] = 6    B[5] = 5
#   B[6] = 3    B[7] = 4    B[8] = 5
#   B[9] = 6    B[10]= 5
# the function should return the following zero-indexed array A1 of M = 9 integers:
#   A1[0] = 2    A1[1] = 2    A1[2] = 2
#   A1[3] = 4    A1[4] = 3    A1[5] = 3
#   A1[6] = 5    A1[7] = 6    A1[8] = 7
# Assume that:
# M and N are integers within the range [0..30,000];
# each element of array A is an integer within the range [0..1,000,000];
# each element of array B is an integer within the range [0..1,000,000].
# Complexity:
# expected worst-case time complexity is O(H+M+N);
# expected worst-case space complexity is O(H+M), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
# Notation used:
# H − max level of a cannonball.
# Elements of input arrays can be modified.
```

***Решение:***

```
#мое наивное решение таково
def solution(A, B):
    for cannonball in range(B[0], len(B)):
        shot(cannonball, A)
    return A


def shot(h, Land):
    if h <= Land[0] or h > max(Land):
        return Land
    for height in range(Land[0], len(Land)):
        if h <= Land[height]:
            Land[height-1] += 1
    return Land


Land = [1, 3, 2, 1, 6]
Balls = [1, 2, 3, 4]

A1 = solution(Land, Balls)

print A1

# >>> [2, 4, 2, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы избежать симуляции полета снаряда (лишнего цикла), нужно использовать в дополнение к A еще один массив Ah - ближайшая точка на данной высоте. В начале этот массив предвычисляется из A, потом на каждой итерации модифицируются A и Ah. Если разброс по высотам большой, то нужно использовать дерево вместо массива. При использовании массива у него сложность доступа константа, у дерева логарифм. Быстрее вложенного перебора получается.

Ну или если под A имеется в виду altitude, то лучше назвать второй массив D (distance).